# Migration from MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, migration

I have a PHP application using PDO for database access.

This application has to be extended to create tables in and write data to a Microsoft SQL-Server (MSSQL) database. For the MSSQL part we don't need transactions.

What are the key points to dive in for migrating existing MySQL queries to MSSQL? Will it be done by switching the PDO database driver or are there differences in SQL dialects when INSERTing data or in login procedures?

Comment: yes there is a difference, just convert your queries to format understandable by mssql. You can use mysqlworkbench

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to changing the connection driver, MySQL and SQL Server have many differences in syntax and features. So, unless your commands are REALY simple, you will probably need some query refactoring.

Now, mapping the from and to codes would depend on the commands you use. For example, if you use LIMIT n directives, you will need to change those to TOP n syntax.

Comment: The MSSQL part should only create tables and write datasets to this table. so basically we just have CREATE TABLE and INSERT SQL commands. Maybe there are differences in indexing and table structuring?

Comment: That will probably make it easier to translate code, but you might still need some refactoring. Anyway, I don't think you will have much trouble with it, but you should check your column types for compatibility.